# Populate dynamically multiple bootstrap dropdown ajax js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, content-management-system

I work with cms so i need help solving this problem! 
I need to populate three bootstrap dropdown lists dynamically, and i can't seem to find the solution anywhere. I need to not load the page when clicking on the menu item, until it clicks the button Submit, then it can show me the content of the categories

```
<div class="btn-group">
                    <button type="button" id="zgjedh-vitin" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle  btn-group1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
                        aria-expanded="false">
                        Zgjedh vitin
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-years ul-deklarimet">
                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="#">Zgjedh vitin</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">2018</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">2017</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">2016</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">2015</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">2014</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">2013</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">2012</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">2011</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">2010</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <button type="button" id="zgjedh-institucionin" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle  btn-group1" data-toggle="dropdown"
                        aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Zgjedh institucionin
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-institucioni ul-deklarimet">
                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="#">Zgjedh institucionin</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Institucionet e Pavarura</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Komunat</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Kuvendi</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Ndermarrjet Publike</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Presidenca</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Qeveria</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <button type="button" id="zgjedh-institucionin-pavarur" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle  btn-group1" data-toggle="dropdown"
                        aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Zgjedh institucionin e pavarur
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu ul-deklarimet">
                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="#">Zgjedh institucionin e pavarur</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Agjencia Kosovare e Privatizimit</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Agjencia Kosovare e Prones</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Agjencia Qendrore e Prokurorimit</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Agjencia Shteterore per Mbrojtjen e te Dhenave Personale</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Agjencia e Intelegjences se Kosoves</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Agjencia kunder Korrupsionit</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Agjencia per Menaxhimin e Komplekseve memoriale te Kosoves</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Agjencia per Ndihme Juridike Falas</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Autoriteti Kosovar i Konkurences</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Autoriteti Kosovar i Hekurudhave</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Autoriteti Rregullativ i Komunikimeve Elektronike dhe Postare
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Autoriteti i Aviacionit Civil></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Banka Qendrore e Kosoves</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Fondi i Kursimeve Pensionale te Kosoves</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Gjykata Kushtetuese</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Institucioni i Avokatit te Popullit</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Instituti Gjyqesor i Kosoves</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Keshilli Gjyqesor i Kosoves-Gjyqtaret</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Keshilli Prokurorial i kosoves-Prokuroret</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Keshilli i Kosoves per Trashigimi Kulturore</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Keshilli i Pavarur Mbikeqyres i Sherbimit Civil te Kosoves</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Komisioni Qendror i Zgjejdheve</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Komisioni Rregullativ i Prokurorimit Publik</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Komisioni i Pavarur i Medieve</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Komisioni i Pavarur per Miniere dhe Minerale</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Organi Shqyrtues i Prokurimit</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Paneli Zgjedhor per Ankesa dhe Parashtresa</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Radio Televizioni i Kosoves</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Zyra e Auditorit te Pergjithshem</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Zyra e Prokurorit Disiplinor</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Zyra e Rregullatorit per Energji</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Zyra e Rregullatorit per Uji dhe Mbeturian</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="kerko-deklarimet">Kerko..
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ajax.json method to dynamically bind the other dropdown.